# Problems with building a project in VB2008

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio, installation

I have a problem with building a project. When I build a project and when I create .exe file, I cannot run it on other computers.
There is an error: "The application failed to initialize properly (0x0000135). Click OK to terminate the application.".

ca i have any chance to solve this error without installing framework 3.5

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If your application requires .NET 3.5 then your users machine will need to it installed.

However, since you're using Visual Studio 2008 you can set your project to target a lower version of the Framework, such as 2.0 which your users might have installed.  Obviously, if you did this your application would not be able to use later Framework features (such as LINQ if you target .NET 2.0).

Comment: i release this application to be used on xp

Comment: @mbayloon Doesn't really change my suggestion - unless there's something I'm not understanding.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you are missing the app.confif file that was generated with the .exe file.